# Where are the elements of an ArcGIS SpatialReference as a string representation defined?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

This seems absurd, but I cannot find any documentation on what the various elements mean in the string representation of an ArcGIS SpatialReference object.  The first part is obviously the Well Known Text representation of the projection but there are 7 parameters, semi-colon separated, that follow it.  The last (7th) is typically "IsHighPrecision" indicating that the high precision grid should be used.

The string can be created using the object's exportToString() method and a SpatialReference can be created from a string using the object's loadFromString() method.  I see examples of using this string to create the reference or used in place of an explicit object (e.g. in CreateFeatureclass examples), but nowhere can I find a "dictionary" of the elements and their default values.

Can someone please point me towards the documentation on this?

Comment: I discussed this recently...where was it...?

Comment: Not what I was looking for, but [this thread](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/40771) has a WKT laid out for the GDB Diagrammer and the extra bits labeled. If anyone wants to put that into an answer, feel free. I just don't have the time right now!

Comment: And [the one](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/116102) I was looking for.

Comment: Melita Kennedy, I should have known you could tell me.  And I'm glad to know what they mean, although this doesn't really answer my question - where is it in the ArcGIS documentation?  The second reference has XML tags so each parameter is separated.  But in the string representation, this is not the case; they are grouped.  So the x-origin, y-origin and xy-scale are space-separated within semi-colons; they constitute the "first" parameter (after WKT string).

Comment: Got stopped by editing time / comment restriction, sorry.  So the WKT string is first parameter, semi-colon.  The x-origin, y-origin and xy-scale are space-separated "2nd" parameter, semi-colon.  The z-origin and z-scale are space-separated "3rd" parameter, semi-colon.
The m-origin and m-scale are space-separated "4th" parameter, semi-colon.  The xy-tolerance is "5th" parameter, semi-colon.  The z-tolerance is "6th" parameter, semi-colon. The m-tolerance is the "7th" parameter, semi-colon.

Comment: And, finally, the IsHighPrecision is the "8th" and final parameter.  Or can there be more (left longitude)?  Or are additional ones only allowed when specified by XML?

Comment: The first thing I found was http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//006z0000000n000000

Comment: LeftLongitude isn't included.

Comment: Vince, thanks for the reference, but this is with respect to the fields (columns) used in SDE GDB table for the Spatial Reference.  Also, it does not store quite the same info as you input; e.g. you input x, y origin values, the table stores x, y offsets (false easting, false northing); not the same thing.  It seems to me that ESRI should have format info for the string representation for EVERY object that supports exportToString() and loadFromString() methods and that doc should be directly linked to object that is being discussed.  This isn't the only one that seems to be missing from help.

Comment: There's a direct correlation to the SE_COORDREF object (coordsys, falsex, falsey, xyscale, falsez, zscale, falsem, mscale, precision).  That page describes how the parameters are used in the computation of coordinates, and links to the column names in the respective implementations.  The Understanding Coordinate Management white paper goes deeper into the weeds http://support.esri.com/es/knowledgebase/whitepapers/view/productid/43/metaid/1301

Comment: Vince, I really appreciate your comments and thank you for the link to the knowledge base white paper.  But these field values simply are not the same as the parameters needed to be specified in the SpatialReference string representation, e.g. falsex is not the same as the coordinate value of the x origin, although you can compute each from the other given the defined (for the PCS) x coordinate value of the origin.  And Melita, your link was enough to get me what I need, so thanks very much.  How do we get it added to the doc (say for 10.3)?

Comment: Too late for 10.3! I've added a request: BUG-000083902.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take Melita Kennedy's [link](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/116102) above as the best answer to what the string representation's elements are.  And note that she's asked for this information to be added to the ArcGIS Help in the future.  Thanks MK!

Also thanks to Vince for additional info.

```
minimum x value
minimum y value
xy precision (1/precision = xy resolution)
minimum z value
z precision
minimum measure value
m precision
xy tolerance
z tolerance
measure tolerance
IsHighPrecision: marker that the spatial reference is high precision, rather than the older standard precision.
```